# Check if local variable is defined given it's name as string in ruby

Tags: ruby, reflection

Can I check if a local variable is defined given it's name as string?

I know there is the function `defined?`, but you have to give the variable itself.

Example:

```
a = 'cat'
print defined?(a) # => "cat"
print defined?(b) # => nil
```

What I need is:

```
a = 'cat'
print string_defined?("a") # => "cat"
print string_defined?("b") # => nil
```

Or something like that. I can't find it in the docs...

I tried to use `respond_to?`, but doesn't seems to work...

Comment: @AndreyDeineko Because I want to do something like: `list_of_strings.reject { |s| !string_defined?(s) }`, with `list_of_strings` parametric.

Comment: Note that all the current answers return `true` even if `a` is defined after the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
a = 'cat'
eval("defined?(#{'a'})")
=> "local-variable"
eval("defined?(#{'b'})")
=> nil
```

Disclaimer: This answer makes use of `eval`, so it can be dangerous if you don't strictly control the string you want to pass into it. And definitely you shouldn't do it this way if these strings come from user input.

Comment: Your answer is correct (the first upvote is from me), but be ready for stupid users starting to downvote on you. Cf. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291823/how-to-deal-with-users-who-unconditionally-react-against-eval.

Comment: This is very clever. This will do **exactly** what I asked, because it uses the original `defined?` method.

Answer (score 4):

The following will return `true` when the local variable in question is (to be) defined in the context, not necessary in a position preceding the point of it:

```
local_variables.include?("a".to_sym)
#=> true
```

Comment: So `local_variables` contains a list of all symbolic names of variables defined in the scope?

Comment: @EricDuminil "This isn't equivalent to defined?"-- Right. And how is that relevant to the question?

Comment: @EricDuminil The question does not mention the timing. Returning whether it is going to be defined in that context is one interpretation of the question. Do not force your interpretation.

Comment: @EricDuminil The situation is the same with the other two (non-deleted) answers. Why do you particularly target this answer?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with Ruby 2.1.0 you can use [`Binding#local_variable_defined?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_defined-3F):

```
a = 'cat'
binding.local_variable_defined? 'a' #=> true
binding.local_variable_defined? 'b' #=> false
```